# php echo same variable multiple times according to each quantity

Tags: php, echo

How to echo same item from mysql database multiple times with each diffrent query example if

catt | qty  | name  | code

WAP |   3   |  shoe  | $query

BOY |   2   |   net  | $query

TIP   |   3      |    phon  | $query

My result set should be like this:
echo

WAP  shoe  113zu1

WAP  shoe  125dj1

WAP  shoe  125332

BOY   net   11331

BOY   net   13wa2

TIP    phon  dej21

TIP    phon  5waja7p2

TIP    phon  532j3

```
i try <?php 
session_start();
include "mysql.php"; 
?>
<?php 
$cartOutput = "";
$product_id_array = '';
if (isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) > 1) { 
  // Start the For Each loop
   $i = 0; 
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
      $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
     $qty = $each_item['quantity'];
}
      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' ORDER BY id");
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
       $product_name = $row["product_name"];
// Create the product array variable
      $product_id_array .= "$item_id-".$each_item['quantity'].","; 
      // Dynamic table row assembly
  for ($b = 1; $b <= $each_item['quantity']; $b++) {
         $cartOutput .= "<tr>";
      $cartOutput .= '<td><a href="product.php?id=' . $item_id . '">' . $product_name . '</a><br /><img src="inventory_images/' . $item_id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name. '" width="40" height="52" border="1" /></td>';
      //$cartOutput .= '<td>' . $each_item['quantity'] . '</td>';
      $cartOutput .= '</tr>';
      $i++; 
    }}
?>
    //output each variable with diffrent code from fetch query
      <?php $query_select = ("SELECT code, FROM diffrent_codes WHERE name='$product_name' ORDER BY id ASC"); $result_select = $mysqli_query($query_select) or die(mysql_error()); $rows = array(); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_select)) $rows[] = $row; foreach($rows as $row){ $code = $row['code']; } echo $cartOutput$code; } ?

 ?>
my $cartOutput$code to output diffrent $code according to each session quantity variable
```

Comment: What is happening that should not be happening or vice versa? You've just chucked code at us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please invest time to looking into prepared statements. PDO will save you from headaches. Also, MySQLi > MySQL.

Now, the reason you don't echo your content multiple times is because you have it set up to echo the row only once. You need a for loop within your while loop that executes as many times as there is quantity. I'll edit with an example later.

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `id` = :item_id ORDER BY `id`");
$sql->bindValue(":item_id", $item_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

if ($sql->execute()) {
    foreach ($sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
        $product_name = $row["product_name"];
        // Dynamic table row assembly

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $row['quantity']; $i++) {
            $cartOutput .= "<tr>";
            $cartOutput .= '<td><a href="product.php?id=' . $item_id . '">' . $product_name . '</a><br /><img src="inventory_images/' . $item_id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name. '" width="40" height="52" border="1" /></td>';
            //$cartOutput .= '<td>' . $row['quantity'] . '</td>';
            $cartOutput .= '</tr>';
        }
    }
}
```